# How do I control the fidelity on the 'image trace' function in illustrator 2020?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace

I was previously using illustrator 2016  on my MacBook... I recently upgraded to the 2020 version and I'm trying to find a way to adjust the **image trace** tool 'fidelity' I think.

If I recall correctly, previously there was an adjustable percentage meter that would make the image less opaque or more opaque, and keeping it at the 95-99 percent range seemed to be my sweet spot for creating an image trace that would smooth out my scanned drawings, but not oversimplify them.

In the new illustrator I've found the image trace function, but its just a button to be clicked without a way to specify the amount. The resulting image trace is a little oversimplified, or low-fidelity if you will, for the effect I'm trying to achieve.

How can I manipulate the level of fidelity, (assumedly by way of adjusting opacity, like I did on previous versions) for the image trace tool on adobe illustrator 2020? Again I'm using a MacBook Pro.

Thanks so much for any assistance!

Comment: Do you have the Image Trace Panel open (WIndow>Image Trace) ? There is an arrow next to where it says Advanced the has what I would consider to be the "fidelity" sliders- I do not remember if in earlier Illustrator versions there was one for opacity.

Comment: wow, thanks! this was everything I needed. not sure why that panel doesn't come up automatically when you go object>image trace! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the Image Trace Panel (Window> Image Trace).

Click the advanced arrow in the panel to access the various parameters you want for the Image Trace.